# Translate "Lengua Bífida" to English

Tags: phrase-requests, translation, spanish

I am trying to translate "Lengua Bífida" from Spanish to English.

The text "Lengua bífida" in Spanish expresses that someone has a tempting form of talking, normally in a bad way.

I was looking for an expression in English that has this meaning, because I don't know if direct translation whould be good in this place.

Comment: Interesting. _Bifid tongue_ according to Google translate. Wonder what that means. Sorry, _Forked tongue_ when I manually selected Spanish as source.

Comment: Cf. *spina bifida*

Comment: Is it a double entendre of speaking with a hidden, often sexy, meaning? A split meaning?

Comment: As @YosefBaskin stated, is something of a split and/or hidden meaning. But I won't say that is sexy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest **forked tongue**. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forked%20tongue) has

> **forked tongue** noun
> : intent to mislead or deceive — usually used in the phrase *to speak with forked tongue*

Also [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/forked+tongue) has

> **forked tongue**
> A trait of someone who speaks in a dishonest or deceitful manner.
> Often used in the phrase "speak with (a) forked tongue."
> *I wouldn't trust a thing Caitlin says, she's always speaking with a forked tongue.*

Comment: The DRAE Spanish dictionary defines *lengua bífida* as *lengua serpentina* and *lengua viperina*. Wiktionary defines *bifid* in English as *forked*. A couple of translations from Linguee.com also show *forked tongue* : https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=%22lengua+b%C3%ADfida%22